# Replace dots in a float column with nan in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, missing-data

I have a data frame df like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    {'Name': 'Chris', 'Item Purchased': 'Sponge', 'Cost': 22.50},
    {'Name': 'Kevyn', 'Item Purchased': 'Kitty Litter', 'Cost': '.........'},
    {'Name': 'Filip', 'Item Purchased': 'Spoon', 'Cost': '...'}],
    index=['Store 1', 'Store 1', 'Store 2'])
```

I want to replace the missing values in 'Cost' columns to `np.nan`. So far I have tried:

```
df['Cost']=df['Cost'].str.replace("\.\.+", np.nan)
```

and

```
df['Cost']=re.sub('\.\.+',np.nan,df['Cost'])
```

but neither of them seem to work properly. Please help.

Comment: `df['Cost']=df['Cost'].replace(".+", np.NaN, regex=True)`

Comment: @VanPeer Not sure why you're offering OP an incorrect solution. If not escaped, the `.` matches anything.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ it worked in this context.. what you meant by matches anything?

Comment: @VanPeer I can't believe it, you're right. I need to find out why that's happening. Try `re.sub('.+', '', '1234')` and you'll understand what I mean.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ thanks, I understood now! #serendipity

Comment: @VanPeer See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47132523/pandas-inconsistency-with-regex-dot-metacharacter/47132524#47132524 :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `DataFrame.replace` with the `regex=True` switch.

```
df = df.replace('\.+', np.nan, regex=True)
df

         Cost Item Purchased   Name
Store 1  22.5         Sponge  Chris
Store 1   NaN   Kitty Litter  Kevyn
Store 2   NaN          Spoon  Filip
```

The pattern `\.+` specifies one or more dots. You could also use `[.]+` as a pattern to the same effect.