# Pandas inconsistency with regex "." dot metacharacter?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Consider

```
df

              Cost
Store 1       22.5
Store 1  .........
Store 2        ...
```

To convert these the dots to nan, I can use:

```
df.replace('^\.+$', np.nan, regex=True)

         Cost
Store 1  22.5
Store 1   NaN
Store 2   NaN
```

What I don't understand is why the following pattern also works:

```
df.replace('^.+$', np.nan, regex=True)

         Cost
Store 1  22.5
Store 1   NaN
Store 2   NaN
```

Note that, in this case, I haven't escaped the `.`, so it should be treated as a matchall character, resulting in every single row being converted to NaN... but it isn't.... only the `....` rows are matched... *even though* I used the matchall character.

Contrast this with:

```
import re
re.sub('^.+$', '', '22.5') 
''
```

Which returns an empty string.

So what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Halfway through writing this question, I realised what the problem was:

```
df.Cost.dtype
dtype('O')

df.Cost.values
array([22.5, '.........', '...'], dtype=object)
```

So, the `22.5` happens to be a numeric value, and the regex pattern simply *skips* over non-string values when attempting to replace. Doing an `astype` conversion makes it obvious:

```
df.astype(str).replace('.+', np.nan, regex=True)

         Cost
Store 1   NaN
Store 1   NaN
Store 2   NaN
```

Problem solved. Leaving this up in case anyone else is confused by this.

Comment: @PJProudhon You can't until 48 hours have passed.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that limitation.

Comment: Or you could use `Series.str.replace`